# How do I use Startactivity and leave the calling Cocos2d Layer active (Android/Java)?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, preferences, cocos2d-android

I'm trying to port my iPhone Cocos2d game to Android using the Cosos2d for Android framework (Java).

I'm running into a problem when I start PreferenceActivity from my main activity. This is my setup:

(1) HelloWordActivity.java:
Inits the Cocos2d environment and starts GameLayer.scene

(2) Gamelayer.scene:
Presents the user with the game but also has a button to show the settingspane which gets called from the Gamelayer class like this:

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       intent.setClassName(helloworldactivity, ShowSettingsActivity.class.getName());
       helloworldactivity.startActivity(intent);
```

This shows the Preference Activity just fine, but when closing the preferences and returning to my game it appears it did not persist (it get's reloaded/restarted and does not retain it's state).

How can I present the user with a standard Android preferences screen without destroying the current game session in Cocos2d ?

Comment: I gave up on Cocos2D for Android. First tried WiEngine but finally settled for ANDEngine, which is good enough for my purposes (a simple card game without too much animations). Switching of activities doesn't destroy the session as was the case with the java port of Cocos2d and also great is that the screen is automatically scaled to larger or smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

from the names of your classes , I'm assuming you used Dan's tutorial as a starter
make sure you remove dan's onStop() override method , that gets called when you are loading the preferences and it calls

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().end();
```

removing this should do it for you

I did notice that you gave up and switched to andEngine , that's a nice engine too but I thought I'd answer this one anyway

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the main activity to start new activity, I hope this code will help you

```
Activity context = CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       intent.setClassName(helloworldactivity, ShowSettingsActivity.class.getName());
       context.startActivity(intent);
```